# TypeScript + React + Emotion: typesafe ref forwarding when using `as`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using emotion and typescript. I have a component which (roughly) looks as follows

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

export default Box = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;
```

In another component, I am using that `div` but using the [`as` prop](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#as-prop) to make it into a button.

However, when I forward the ref, I want to appropriately type it to be the type of whatever that element is. i.e.,

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import Box from '../Box';

const Button = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <Box {...props} as="button" ref={ref} />;
});
```

If I took this one step further, ideally `as` could be anything that is accepted by `styled.div()` and know what the type of ref would be.

However, I can't find the appropriate way to type `ref` in a way that matches as expected.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
interface ButtonProps = {
  props: {}
}

const Button = forwardRef(({ ...props }: ButtonProps, ref?: React.Ref<HTMLButtonElement & HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
  return <Box {...props} as="button" ref={ref} />;
});
```